# Remover imagem pdf usando itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Estou adicionando imagem no pdf com itext, porém em alguns momentos preciso remover esta mesma imagem.. como faço isso de forma a não corromper a leitura do mesmo?
Já tentei de algumas formas, conforme segue abaixo:

A primeira tentativa foi limpar os streams refente a imagem

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));

    for(int i = 0; i < reader.getXrefSize(); i++)
    {
        PdfObject obj = reader.getPdfObject(i);
        if(obj == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if(obj.isStream())
        {
            PdfStream stream = (PdfStream) obj;

            PdfObject subtype = stream.get(PdfName.SUBTYPE);

            if(PdfName.IMAGE.equals(subtype))
            {
                stream.clear();
            }
        }
    }

    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
```

Isso causa erro ao ler o arquivo com o Adobe reader, este leitor entende que o arquivo esta corrompido. Demais leitores como Foxit funciona perfeitamente.

A segunda tentativa foi alterar as propriedades da imagem, ou seja, alterar a altura e largura para 1px. Porém ao alterar as propriedades, ainda esta ficando uma "pelicula" do mesmo tamanho da imagem, a qual não consigo remover

```
   PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
   PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));

    for(int i = 0; i < reader.getXrefSize(); i++)
    {
        PdfObject obj = reader.getPdfObject(i);
        if(obj == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if(obj.isStream())
        {
            PdfStream stream = (PdfStream) obj;

            PdfObject subtype = stream.get(PdfName.SUBTYPE);

            if(PdfName.IMAGE.equals(subtype))
            {
                stream.put(PdfName.WIDTH, new PdfNumber(1));
                stream.put(PdfName.HEIGHT, new PdfNumber(1));
            }
        }
    }

    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
```

Alguém saberia dizer o que posso fazer para remover a imagem?